# background-image:no-repeat not working, syntax is correct

Tags: html, css

Below is the syntax I am using for the background Image.  For some reason it is repeating on **Y**.  I cannot use `overflow:hidden;`

```
<style>
body {
    background-image: url('<?php echo $ActualPath; ?>images/backgroundimage.jpg'); 
    background-image: no-repeat;
}    
</style>
```

I want the background-image no-repeat on x and y.

Comment: Don't you want background-repeat: no-repeat instead of background-image?

Comment: Syntax is not correct acording to who?

Comment: hahaha I love the title of this question `syntax is correct`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The syntax you should use is

```
background-image: url(path/images/backgroundimage.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

.. or alternatively

```
background: url(path/images/backgroundimage.jpg) no-repeat;
```

if you prefer the [short-hand syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background#Values).

`background-image` always just defines an image file, so in your example, the second `background-image` rule is attempting to override the first one, but since "no-repeat" isn't a valid image file the browser just ignores it.

The various background properties are listed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background#Values) for reference.

Comment: The background does not repeat, but its white image after that.

Comment: What should there be instead of white? Could you link to an example - it's quite hard to tell what's wrong otherwise?

Comment: Cannot believe order matters but it seems it does :\

Comment: @rogerdpack not sure what you mean. The later rule will override the earlier rule. How else would it work?

Answer (score 3):

The `background` property has a few properties you can change.

- background-color
- background-image
- background-repeat
- background-attachment
- background-position

You can set each one individually, like what you're trying to do. If you set the same one twice, only the last one will take effect.

You're setting `background-image` twice where the second one should be `background-repeat`.

There is also a shorthand notation where you do something like

```
background:#ffffff url('img_tree.png') no-repeat right top;
```

to set multiple properties in one line. You could use that to change your code to

```
body{ background: url('<?php echo $ActualPath; ?>images/backgroundimage.jpg') no-repeat; }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `background-repeat:no-repeat;`

Answer (score -2):

For getting no repeat of background in html use this syntax:
 CSS(Internal stylesheet)
use this code in style tag in head part

```
background-image:url("some picture url");
background-repeat:no repeat;
```

-It will provide background image of single view without repeatation.